# One of two meta keys is being ignored by WP_Query

Tags: php, metadata, wordpress

My meta queries are very inconsistent. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Both meta keys are ACF plugin's. The first key, **"polecany"**, is a checkbox with value "polecany" when checked. The second key, **"segment"**, is a dropdown list from which you select where you would like your post to be on the page.

***My problem:***

This query correctly finds posts with the key "polecany", but completely ignores the "segment" key. It doesn't matter which posts have which "segment". This query just loads them all.

As you can see - both queries are wrapped up with an "AND" statement.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second array inside your meta query has incorrect keys therefore is being ignored.

In the first one you'll notice you use the keys `key` and `value`. In the second array you use `meta_key` and `meta_value`. Change them to match the first and your query will work.

Comment: Oh yes, I completely missed that. Thank you very much.